# Assertion when using MKMapView - CarrierName and depthStencilState

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, metal

I'm finishing my app for release and found a bug. I have a couple of `UITableViewControllers` with cells that contain a `MKMapView` control.

Sometimes, when the view is displayed, my app crashes. The log shows the following messages:

> [LogMessageLogging] 6.1 Unable to retrieve CarrierName. CTError: domain-2, code-5, errStr:((os/kern) failure)
>   -[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setDepthStencilState:]:2077: failed assertion `depthStencilState is associated with a different device'

The CarrierName does not crash the app (it is still confusing why this log message appears), but the second one crashes my app.

How can I fix this error? Can I suppress the assertion?

Here is all of the table view code:

```
// Mark: TableView

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.activities.count
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellFeed") as! ActivityCell

    if indexPath.row >= self.activities.count
    {
        return cell
    }

    let activity = self.activities[indexPath.row]

    cell.activity = activity
    cell.name.text = activity.name
    if activity.distance != nil
    {
        cell.distance.text = String(format: "%.2f km", activity.distance!.floatValue / 1000)
    }
    if activity.elevationGain != nil
    {
        cell.elevation.text = String(format: "%d m", Int(activity.elevationGain!))
    }
    if activity.date != nil
    {
        cell.date.text = DateHelper.getDateString(date: activity.date!)
    }

    // Map
    if activity.map != nil && activity.map!.summary != nil
    {
        var coordinates = PolylineDecoder.decode(activity.map!.summary!)

        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            // Clear old overlays
            cell.map.removeOverlays(cell.map.overlays)

            cell.map.delegate = self
            let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
            cell.map.add(polyline)
            cell.map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(polyline.boundingMapRect), animated: false)
        }
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let index = indexPath.row

    if index < self.activities.count
    {
        let activity = self.activities[index]
        Utilities.post(Notifications.ActivityClicked, activity)

        if self.navigationController != nil
        {
            self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Map
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
{
    let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 1
    return polylineRenderer
}
```

Comment: I have got the same problem in using map view. Don't know how to fix.

Comment: Does this happen when you launch your app on the device instead of from Xcode?